# Passing integer values from view to controller (mvc) through href

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I 'm doing a dot net project (MVC) in which I want to pass integers (hard coded university ids) from view to Controller.
In view I 'm doing

```
<a href="/Admin/applied/1">PU</a>
<a href="/Admin/applied/2">UET</a>
<a href="/Admin/applied/3">GC</a>
```

where admin is the CONTROLLER & applied is ACTION METHOD

in ACTION METHOD (applied in Admin)

```
public ActionResult applied(string uniId)
{
    Processing of admissions on the basis of uniId
}
```

but when I 'm compiling this , uniId contains NULL instead of actual integer passed by `<a href="/Admin/applied/1">PU</a>` etc.
Kindly help me out

Comment: Do you have a specific route defined for this action that has a parameter named `uniID`? If not create one or change your method to `public ActionResult applied(string id)` to match the default route

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your point, my method is already public ActionResult applied(string uniId), what route define?

Comment: Show your routes! And its not `(string id)` it `(string uniId)`. Change `uniId` to `id`

Comment: Admin{Controller}/Applied{actionMethod}
what do you mean by "ROUTES"?

Comment: The routes as defined in the `route.config.cs` file

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET MVC will only provide the value if the parameter is named `id`. You have to options. First is renaming the parameter:

```
public ActionResult applied(string id)
{
    Processing of admissions on the basis of uniId
}
```

Second is creating a  new route in RouteConfig **above the default route**:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Applied", // Route name
        "Admin/applied/{uniId}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Admin", action = "applied" } // Parameter defaults
        );
```